# ¿Cual es la mejor forma de crear un Excel con mas de 400,000 registros y mas de 20 columnas?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, epplus

Como lo dice el titulo , cual es la mejor manera de crear un excel con mas de **400,000 registros,** les comentare mi situación, tengo un reporteador el cual crea el reporte en base a la información obtenida de la base de datos la cual genera mas de 400,000 registros , al momento de estar construyendo el excel en algunas ocasiones si no es que en la mayoria me marca que se quedo sin memoria 
Mensaje: **"SE PRODUJO UNA EXCEPCIÓN DE TIPO 'SYSTEM.OUTOFMEMORYEXCEPTION'"**

buscando en blogs encontré que la mejor manera es dividir en grupos e insertarlos en cada hoja de excel , si me aligero un poco el proceso  ya no trono tantas veces el proceso pero si me ha seguido marcando el error antes mencionado , actualmente estoy usando la librería de **EPPLUS** la cual me a resultado bastante bien pero para crear archivos con mas de cuatrocientos mil registros y **mas de 20 columnas** no lo hace de la mejor manera, acudo a ustedes para saber en **como puedo mejorar mi método para crear y o sugerirme alguna otra librería que si pueda con la carga de tanta información**.

**Error:**

> SYSTEM.OUTOFMEMORYEXCEPTION: SE PRODUJO UNA EXCEPCIÓN DE TIPO 'SYSTEM.OUTOFMEMORYEXCEPTION'.
>      EN SYSTEM.COLLECTIONS.GENERIC.LIST`1.SET_CAPACITY(INT32 VALUE)
>      EN SYSTEM.COLLECTIONS.GENERIC.LIST`1.ENSURECAPACITY(INT32 MIN)
>      EN SYSTEM.COLLECTIONS.GENERIC.LIST`1.ADD(T ITEM)
>      EN CELLSTORE`1.ADDCELL(COLUMNINDEX COLUMNINDEX, INT32 PAGEPOS, INT32 POS, INT16 IX, T VALUE)
>      EN CELLSTORE`1.SETVALUESPECIAL(INT32 ROW, INT32 COLUMN, SETVALUEDELEGATE UPDATER, OBJECT VALUE)
>      EN OFFICEOPENXML.EXCELRANGEBASE.SET_VALUE(EXCELRANGEBASE RANGE, OBJECT VALUE, INT32 ROW, INT32 COL)
>      EN OFFICEOPENXML.EXCELRANGEBASE.SETSINGLE(EXCELRANGEBASE RANGE, _SETVALUE VALUEMETHOD, OBJECT VALUE)
>      EN OFFICEOPENXML.EXCELRANGEBASE.SET_VALUE(OBJECT VALUE)
>      EN INTERFACEMONTERREY.CONTROLLERS.PREDIALCONTROLLER.REPORTEREGERADEUDOS(CAMPOSREPORTE2 CR)

**Anexo mi codigo :**

```
public ActionResult ReporteR(CamposReporte2 cr)
    {
        try
        {
            //string TipoPer = string.Empty;

            //llena la lista
            List<Reporte_tbl_tmp_RegerAdeudos> ListaRepRegerAd = new List<Reporte_tbl_tmp_RegerAdeudos>(GetRegistros(TempData["Fecha_Actualizacion"].ToString()));

            //var registros=GetRegistros(camposRep.FechaIn, camposRep.FechaFin, camposRep.TipoPersona);
            string excelName = "Reporte Predial " + DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
            //Directorio
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"));
            FileInfo excelFile = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + excelName + ".xlsx"));

            //si existe el archivo lo borra
            if (excelFile.Exists)
            {
                excelFile.Delete();
            }

            const int maxExcelRows = 100000;

            // ExcelPackage excelp = new ExcelPackage();
            using (var excelp = new ExcelPackage(excelFile))
            {
                //Assume a data row count
                var rowCount = ListaRepRegerAd.Count();

                //Determine number of sheets
                var sheetCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)rowCount / maxExcelRows);

                for (var i = 0; i < sheetCount; i++)
                {
                    var worksheet = excelp.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(String.Format("Reporte_Predial {0}", i));
                    worksheet.TabColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                    worksheet.DefaultRowHeight = 12;

                    var sheetRowLimit = Math.Min((i + 1) * maxExcelRows, rowCount);

                    #region encabezado excel
                    //Encabezado
                    worksheet.Row(1).Height = 20;
                    worksheet.Row(1).Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
                    worksheet.Row(1).Style.Font.Bold = true;
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "EXPEDIENTE";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Nombre_del_Propietario";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = "Domicilio";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 4].Value = "Número_Exterior_Domicilio";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 5].Value = "Número_Interior_Domicilio";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 6].Value = "Coloni_Domicilio";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 7].Value = "Ubicación";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 8].Value = "Número_Exterior_Ubicación";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 9].Value = "Número_Interior_Ubicación";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 10].Value = "Colonia_Ubicación";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 11].Value = "Valor_Catastral";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 12].Value = "Valor_Catastral_Terreno";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 13].Value = "Valor_Catastral_Construccion";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 14].Value = "Periodo";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 15].Value = "Rezago_Anteriores";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 16].Value = "Actual_5";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 17].Value = "Actual_4";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 18].Value = "Actual_3";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 19].Value = "Actual_2";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 20].Value = "Actual_1";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 21].Value = "Total_anio_Rezago";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 22].Value = "Actual_anio_en_curso";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 23].Value = "Total_de_Impuesto";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 24].Value = "Bonificación_Impuesto";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 25].Value = "Actualización";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 26].Value = "Actualización_Anterior";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 27].Value = "Subsidio_Actualización";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 28].Value = "Recargo";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 29].Value = "Recargo_Anteriores";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 30].Value = "Subsidio_Recargo";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 31].Value = "Gastos";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 32].Value = "Gastos_Anteriores";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 33].Value = "Subsidio_Gastos";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 34].Value = "Sanción";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 35].Value = "Sanción_Anteriores";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 36].Value = "Subsidio_Sanción";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 37].Value = "Total_de_subsidio";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 38].Value = "Total_a_pagar";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 39].Value = "Clave_de_Exento";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 40].Value = "Uso_de_Suelo";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 41].Value = "Tipo_de_Terreno";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 42].Value = "Status_1";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 43].Value = "Status_2";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 44].Value = "Status_3";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 45].Value = "Status_4";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 46].Value = "Status_5";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 47].Value = "Status_6";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 48].Value = "Motivo_de_Movimiento";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 49].Value = "Fecha_de_Movimiento";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 50].Value = "USUARIO";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 51].Value = "FECHA_DE_ACTUALIZACION";
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 52].Value = "FECHA_Y_HORA_DE_ACTUALIZACION";
                    #endregion

                    #region cuerpo excel
                    //Cuerpo del excel
                    int recordIndex = 2;
                    int ContadorReg = 0;

                    #region paginacion
                    var listaPaginada = (from l in ListaRepRegerAd
                                         select new Reporte_tbl_tmp_RegerAdeudos
                                         {
                                             EXPEDIENTE = l.EXPEDIENTE,
                                             Nombre_del_Propietario = l.Nombre_del_Propietario,
                                             Domicilio = l.Domicilio,
                                             Numero_Exterior_Domicilio = l.Numero_Exterior_Domicilio,
                                             Numero_Interior_Domicilio = l.Numero_Interior_Domicilio,
                                             Coloni_Domicilio = l.Coloni_Domicilio,
                                             Ubicacion = l.Ubicacion,
                                             Numero_Exterior_Ubicacion = l.Numero_Exterior_Ubicacion,
                                             Numero_Interior_Ubicacion = l.Numero_Interior_Ubicacion,
                                             Colonia_Ubicacion = l.Colonia_Ubicacion,
                                             Valor_Catastral = l.Valor_Catastral,
                                             Valor_Catastral_Terreno = l.Valor_Catastral_Terreno,
                                             Valor_Catastral_Construccion = l.Valor_Catastral_Construccion,
                                             Periodo = l.Periodo,
                                             Rezago_Anteriores = l.Rezago_Anteriores,
                                             Actual_5 = l.Actual_5,
                                             Actual_4 = l.Actual_4,
                                             Actual_3 = l.Actual_3,
                                             Actual_2 = l.Actual_2,
                                             Actual_1 = l.Actual_1,
                                             Total_anio_Rezago = l.Total_anio_Rezago,
                                             Actual_anio_en_curso = l.Actual_anio_en_curso,
                                             Total_de_Impuesto = l.Total_de_Impuesto,
                                             Bonificacion_Impuesto = l.Bonificacion_Impuesto,
                                             Actualizacion = l.Actualizacion,
                                             Actualizacion_Anterior = l.Actualizacion_Anterior,
                                             Subsidio_Actualizacion = l.Subsidio_Actualizacion,
                                             Recargo = l.Recargo,
                                             Recargo_Anteriores = l.Recargo_Anteriores,
                                             Subsidio_Recargo = l.Subsidio_Recargo,
                                             Gastos = l.Gastos,
                                             Gastos_Anteriores = l.Gastos_Anteriores,
                                             Subsidio_Gastos = l.Subsidio_Gastos,
                                             Sancion = l.Sancion,
                                             Sancion_Anteriores = l.Sancion_Anteriores,
                                             Subsidio_Sancion = l.Subsidio_Sancion,
                                             Total_de_subsidio = l.Total_de_subsidio,
                                             Total_a_pagar = l.Total_a_pagar,
                                             Clave_de_Exento = l.Clave_de_Exento,
                                             Uso_de_Suelo = l.Uso_de_Suelo,
                                             Tipo_de_Terreno = l.Tipo_de_Terreno,
                                             Status_1 = l.Status_1,
                                             Status_2 = l.Status_2,
                                             Status_3 = l.Status_3,
                                             Status_4 = l.Status_4,
                                             Status_5 = l.Status_5,
                                             Status_6 = l.Status_6,
                                             Motivo_de_Movimiento = l.Motivo_de_Movimiento,
                                             Fecha_de_Movimiento = l.Fecha_de_Movimiento,
                                             USUARIO = l.USUARIO,
                                             FECHA_DE_ACTUALIZACION = l.FECHA_DE_ACTUALIZACION,
                                             FECHA_Y_HORA_DE_ACTUALIZACION = l.FECHA_Y_HORA_DE_ACTUALIZACION

                                         }).Skip((i) * maxExcelRows).Take(maxExcelRows);
                    #endregion


                    foreach (Reporte_tbl_tmp_RegerAdeudos rra in listaPaginada)
                    //Remember +1 for 1-based excel index
                    {

                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 1].Value = rra.EXPEDIENTE;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 2].Value = rra.Nombre_del_Propietario;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 3].Value = rra.Domicilio;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 4].Value = rra.Numero_Exterior_Domicilio;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 5].Value = rra.Numero_Interior_Domicilio;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 6].Value = rra.Coloni_Domicilio;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 7].Value = rra.Ubicacion;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 8].Value = rra.Numero_Interior_Ubicacion;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 9].Value = rra.Numero_Exterior_Ubicacion;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 10].Value = rra.Colonia_Ubicacion;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 11].Value = rra.Valor_Catastral;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 12].Value = rra.Valor_Catastral_Terreno;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 13].Value = rra.Valor_Catastral_Construccion;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 14].Value = rra.Periodo;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 15].Value = rra.Rezago_Anteriores;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 16].Value = rra.Actual_5;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 17].Value = rra.Actual_4;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 18].Value = rra.Actual_3;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 19].Value = rra.Actual_2;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 20].Value = rra.Actual_1;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 21].Value = rra.Total_anio_Rezago;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 22].Value = rra.Actual_anio_en_curso;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 23].Value = rra.Total_de_Impuesto;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 24].Value = rra.Bonificacion_Impuesto;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 25].Value = rra.Actualizacion;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 26].Value = rra.Actualizacion_Anterior;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 27].Value = rra.Subsidio_Actualizacion;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 28].Value = rra.Recargo;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 29].Value = rra.Recargo_Anteriores;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 30].Value = rra.Subsidio_Recargo;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 31].Value = rra.Gastos;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 32].Value = rra.Gastos_Anteriores;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 33].Value = rra.Subsidio_Gastos;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 34].Value = rra.Sancion;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 35].Value = rra.Sancion_Anteriores;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 36].Value = rra.Subsidio_Sancion;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 37].Value = rra.Total_de_subsidio;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 38].Value = rra.Total_a_pagar;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 39].Value = rra.Clave_de_Exento;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 40].Value = rra.Uso_de_Suelo;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 41].Value = rra.Tipo_de_Terreno;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 42].Value = rra.Status_1;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 43].Value = rra.Status_2;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 44].Value = rra.Status_3;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 45].Value = rra.Status_4;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 46].Value = rra.Status_5;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 47].Value = rra.Status_6;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 48].Value = rra.Motivo_de_Movimiento;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 49].Value = rra.Fecha_de_Movimiento;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 50].Value = rra.USUARIO;
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 51].Value = rra.FECHA_DE_ACTUALIZACION.ToString();
                        worksheet.Cells[recordIndex, 52].Value = rra.FECHA_Y_HORA_DE_ACTUALIZACION.ToString();

                        recordIndex++;

                        ViewBag.ContadorRegistros = ContadorReg++;

                    }


                    #endregion

                    #region formato de celdas
                    worksheet.Column(1).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(2).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(3).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(4).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(5).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(6).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(7).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(8).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(9).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(10).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(11).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(12).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(13).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(14).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(15).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(16).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(17).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(18).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(19).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(20).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(21).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(22).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(23).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(24).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(25).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(26).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(27).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(28).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(29).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(30).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(31).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(32).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(33).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(34).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(35).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(36).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(37).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(38).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(39).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(40).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(41).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(42).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(43).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(44).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(45).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(46).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(47).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(48).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(49).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(50).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(51).AutoFit();
                    worksheet.Column(52).AutoFit();
                    #endregion
                }

                excelp.Save();
            }



            TempData["ExcelName"] = excelName;
            //if (recordIndex > 2)
            //{

            //    //Recorre la carpeta para revisar si tiene arcvhivos
            //    foreach (FileInfo fileIn in di.GetFiles())
            //    {
            //        //Elimina el archivo si exite
            //        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileIn.FullName))
            //        {
            //            System.IO.File.Delete(fileIn.FullName);
            //        }
            //    }


            //    excelp.SaveAs(excelFile);

            //    return View();
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    //TipoPersona t = new TipoPersona();
            //    //ViewBag.ddl = t.CargaTipoPersona();
            //    ModelState.AddModelError("", "No se encontraron registros en el rango de fecha seleccionada.");
            //    Response.Write("<script>alert('No se encontraron registros.');</script>");

            //    return View();
            //}
            return View();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "No se pudo generar el Excel - " + ex.Message);
            log.ErrorLog(ex.ToString());
            ViewBag.ContadorRegistros = 0;
            // return RedirectToAction("ReporteRegerAdeudos", "Predial");
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: No hay una mejor forma, no deberias generar este tipo de reportes, deberias dar la posibilidad al usuario de filtrar los datos que realmente va autilizar. Igualmente recuerdo que el excel tiene la posibilidad de importar datos cuando los usas en `pivot` y soporta mucha informacion

Comment: hola @LeandroTuttini , de hecho si los ocupa todos , ya que se hace un análisis en cuanto al reporte con los datos recabados.

Comment: pero ante ese volumne de datos el analisis deberias hacerlo en otra tool, o como comente ver la funcionalidad de importacion de datos que se usa en el pivot de excel, este si permite mas informaicon que las celdas. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-with-an-external-data-source-db50d01d-2e1c-43bd-bfb5-b76a818a927b

Comment: No debería de haber interfaz de usuario para archivos tan grandes, puedes ejecutar una tarea asíncrona que realice ese trabajo y escriba directo de la base a archivo, luego el archivo se coloca en cierta ruta temporal donde se pueda descargar. Eso o como dicen arriba, filtrar y crear reportes más pequeños

Comment: @shop350 y si lo creo como xml y pasarlo a excel despues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por fin encontre una solucion y la clave estaba en la documentacion de la libreria , y mas rapido y simple con una linea en vez de usar el foreach era pasar directamente la coleccion

**Con esta linea me ahorre recorrer la colección**

```
//add all the content from the List<Book> collection, starting at cell A1
worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(books);
```

**Anexo el codigo y las fuentes de donde lo saque** 
Fuente: [Documentacion](https://riptutorial.com/Download/epplus.pdf);
Enlace de la solucion: [solucion](https://riptutorial.com/epplus/example/26425/fill-from-collection)

```
 public ActionResult ReporteRegerAdeudos(CamposReporte2 cr)
    {
        try
        {
            //string TipoPer = string.Empty;

            //llena la lista
            List<Reporte_tbl_tmp_RegerAdeudos> ListaRepRegerAd = new List<Reporte_tbl_tmp_RegerAdeudos>(GetRegistros(TempData["Fecha_Actualizacion"].ToString()));

            //var registros=GetRegistros(camposRep.FechaIn, camposRep.FechaFin, camposRep.TipoPersona);
            string excelName = "Reporte Predial " + DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
            //Directorio
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"));
            FileInfo excelFile = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + excelName + ".xlsx"));

            //si existe el archivo lo borra
            if (excelFile.Exists)
            {
                excelFile.Delete();
            }

            // ExcelPackage excelp = new ExcelPackage();
            using (var excelp = new ExcelPackage(excelFile))
            {
                var worksheet = excelp.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(String.Format("Reporte_Predial"));


                #region encabezado excel
                //Encabezado
                worksheet.Row(1).Height = 20;
                worksheet.Row(1).Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
                worksheet.Row(1).Style.Font.Bold = true;
                worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "EXPEDIENTE";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Nombre_del_Propietario";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = "Domicilio";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 4].Value = "Número_Exterior_Domicilio";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 5].Value = "Número_Interior_Domicilio";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 6].Value = "Coloni_Domicilio";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 7].Value = "Ubicación";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 8].Value = "Número_Exterior_Ubicación";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 9].Value = "Número_Interior_Ubicación";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 10].Value = "Colonia_Ubicación";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 11].Value = "Valor_Catastral";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 12].Value = "Valor_Catastral_Terreno";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 13].Value = "Valor_Catastral_Construccion";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 14].Value = "Periodo";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 15].Value = "Rezago_Anteriores";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 16].Value = "Actual_5";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 17].Value = "Actual_4";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 18].Value = "Actual_3";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 19].Value = "Actual_2";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 20].Value = "Actual_1";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 21].Value = "Total_anio_Rezago";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 22].Value = "Actual_anio_en_curso";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 23].Value = "Total_de_Impuesto";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 24].Value = "Bonificación_Impuesto";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 25].Value = "Actualización";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 26].Value = "Actualización_Anterior";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 27].Value = "Subsidio_Actualización";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 28].Value = "Recargo";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 29].Value = "Recargo_Anteriores";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 30].Value = "Subsidio_Recargo";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 31].Value = "Gastos";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 32].Value = "Gastos_Anteriores";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 33].Value = "Subsidio_Gastos";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 34].Value = "Sanción";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 35].Value = "Sanción_Anteriores";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 36].Value = "Subsidio_Sanción";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 37].Value = "Total_de_subsidio";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 38].Value = "Total_a_pagar";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 39].Value = "Clave_de_Exento";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 40].Value = "Uso_de_Suelo";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 41].Value = "Tipo_de_Terreno";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 42].Value = "Status_1";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 43].Value = "Status_2";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 44].Value = "Status_3";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 45].Value = "Status_4";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 46].Value = "Status_5";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 47].Value = "Status_6";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 48].Value = "Motivo_de_Movimiento";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 49].Value = "Fecha_de_Movimiento";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 50].Value = "USUARIO";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 51].Value = "FECHA_DE_ACTUALIZACION";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 52].Value = "FECHA_Y_HORA_DE_ACTUALIZACION";
                #endregion

                //add all the content from the List<Book> collection, starting at cell A1
                worksheet.Cells["A2"].LoadFromCollection(ListaRepRegerAd);

                ViewBag.ContadorRegistros = worksheet.Cells.Count();

                #region formato de celdas
                //worksheet.Column(1).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(2).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(3).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(4).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(5).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(6).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(7).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(8).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(9).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(10).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(11).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(12).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(13).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(14).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(15).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(16).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(17).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(18).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(19).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(20).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(21).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(22).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(23).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(24).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(25).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(26).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(27).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(28).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(29).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(30).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(31).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(32).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(33).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(34).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(35).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(36).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(37).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(38).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(39).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(40).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(41).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(42).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(43).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(44).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(45).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(46).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(47).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(48).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(49).AutoFit();
                //worksheet.Column(50).AutoFit();
                worksheet.Column(51).Style.Numberformat.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm";
                worksheet.Column(52).Style.Numberformat.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm";
                #endregion

                excelp.Save();
            }

            TempData["ExcelName"] = excelName;

            return View();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "No se pudo generar el Excel - " + ex.Message);
            log.ErrorLog(ex.ToString());
            ViewBag.ContadorRegistros = 0;
            // return RedirectToAction("ReporteRegerAdeudos", "Predial");
            return View();
        }
    }
```